# Как корректно перейти с Jade на Pug?

Tags: node.js, jade, pug

Здравствуйте. Я создал чистый проект при помощи [express-generator'а](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) и проверив его на устаревшие зависимости при помощи [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check), начал их обновлять. Всё обновилось успешно, кроме jade, который недавно [сменил имя](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184). NPM пишет по этому поводу следующее:

> npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade

Я выполнил следующие команды:

```
npm uninstall --save jade
npm install --save pug
npm start
```

Сервер запустился, но при переходе на localhost:3000 упал с ошибкой 'Error: Cannot find module 'jade'. Тогда я обновил в коде app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

на

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

и сервер падает с новой ошибкой: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "~/documents/projects/node/template/views"

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Всё, спасибо, разобрался методом тыка! :) Нужно было в папке views переименовать все файлы *.jade на *.pug!

Comment: Также само переходил) Правда делал еще в IDE ассоциацию Pug-файлов c Jade, пока первое время небыло плагинов с поддержкой синтаксиса.

Answer (score -1):

У меня проблема решилась сама собой после

```
npm-check -u
```